# How can i increment the index of an array and return the result in an html tag when user click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create cbt software with javascript, and i have an external .js file where i stored my question. I displayed the first question in an html tag when the document is ready, so now i what the question to change and display on the same html tag, according to the index in the array when the user click on next button and the same as previous. This is giving me tough time.
I hope you get my Question right. Here is my code

```
var pos = Number(0);
var question = physics[pos][0];
var optiona = physics[pos][1];
var optionb = physics[pos][2];
var optionc = physics[pos][3];
var optiond = physics[pos][4];
var answer = physics[pos][5];
var ans = physics[pos][6];
var length = physics.length;
var len = length + 1;
var html = " ";

function loadq() {
  html += '<div id="subject1" class="tab-pane fade in active animated slideInRight">';
  html += ' <div class="clearfix"></div><br />';
  html += '<div class="row" style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;">';
  html += '<div class="panel panel-success" style="border:5px solid #e1f4e6">';
  html += '<div class="panel-heading" style="color:red">QUESTION NO: ' + (parseInt(pos) + 1) + ' of  ' + len + '<span id="questno"></span></div>';
  // html += '<h4 style="color:red !important">' + (parseInt(id) + 1) +'</h4>';
  html += '<div style="padding:20px">';
  html += '<div id="diagram"></div>';
  html += '<div id="question">' + question + '</div>';
  html += '<hr>';
  html += '<div class="examcontainer">';
  html += '<fieldset>';

  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="A"><label for="A">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">A.</span>&nbsp; ' + optiona + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="B"><label for="B">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">B.</span>&nbsp; ' + optionb + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="C"><label for="C">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">C.</span>&nbsp; ' + optionc + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="D"><label for="D">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">D.</span>&nbsp; ' + optiond + '</label></div>';

  html += '</div></fieldset></div>';
  //if (json.rows[id].answer == '')
  //json.rows[id].answer = '<span style="color:#2E68BC !important">The correct answer is option <strong>[' + json.rows[id].correct_answer + ']</strong></span>';
  html += '<label style="color:#880000;" class="mycorrectanswer">' + answer + '</label>';
  html += '</span>';
  html += '</div></div></div>';

  $('#mainslide_0').html(html);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loadq();

  $("#nextButton").click(function() {
    //$('#mainslide_0').html(physics[pos]).html(html);
    pos++;

    //}
  });

  $("#prevButton").click(function() {
    if (pos == 0) {
      return false
      pos--
    }
    //$('#mainslide_0').html(html);
  });
});
```

[image: Here is the image i attac]

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking removing 1 from the `pos` variable because returning a value in JavaScript essentially terminates the execution of the function.

This should work:

```
var pos = Number(0);
var question = physics[pos][0];
var optiona = physics[pos][1];
var optionb = physics[pos][2];
var optionc = physics[pos][3];
var optiond = physics[pos][4];
var answer = physics[pos][5];
var ans = physics[pos][6];
var length = physics.length;
var len = length + 1;
var html = " ";

function loadq() {
  html += '<div id="subject1" class="tab-pane fade in active animated slideInRight">';
  html += ' <div class="clearfix"></div><br />';
  html += '<div class="row" style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;">';
  html += '<div class="panel panel-success" style="border:5px solid #e1f4e6">';
  html += '<div class="panel-heading" style="color:red">QUESTION NO: ' + (parseInt(pos) + 1) + ' of  ' + len + '<span id="questno"></span></div>';
  // html += '<h4 style="color:red !important">' + (parseInt(id) + 1) +'</h4>';
  html += '<div style="padding:20px">';
  html += '<div id="diagram"></div>';
  html += '<div id="question">' + question + '</div>';
  html += '<hr>';
  html += '<div class="examcontainer">';
  html += '<fieldset>';

  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="A"><label for="A">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">A.</span>&nbsp; ' + optiona + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="B"><label for="B">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">B.</span>&nbsp; ' + optionb + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="C"><label for="C">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">C.</span>&nbsp; ' + optionc + '</label></div>';
  html += '<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="examoption" id="optiona"  value="D"><label for="D">&nbsp;<span style="color:#0F5333; font-size:12pt;">D.</span>&nbsp; ' + optiond + '</label></div>';

  html += '</div></fieldset></div>';
  //if (json.rows[id].answer == '')
  //json.rows[id].answer = '<span style="color:#2E68BC !important">The correct answer is option <strong>[' + json.rows[id].correct_answer + ']</strong></span>';
  html += '<label style="color:#880000;" class="mycorrectanswer">' + answer + '</label>';
  html += '</span>';
  html += '</div></div></div>';

  $('#mainslide_0').html(html);
}

var update = function() {

    loadq();

};

$("#prevButton").click(function() {

    if (pos == 0) {

        return false;

    }

    pos = pos - 1;

    update();

});

$("#nextButton").click(function() {

    pos = pos + 1;

    update();

});
```

Comment: what i mean is that as the user click the next question, the question should change too and the same as previous

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: it works with incrementing but only append the questions, on click please help

Comment: I cant see the issue because i dont have all the code. Stackoverflow is not a "code this for me" service. I have solved the problem which you asked the question for, so please accept my answer.